# Is there a single word meaning the same as "to pull the rug out from under one's feet"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm sure there was one, I just can't remember what it is, and the ones I keep coming up with (like "challenge") don't seem to fit.

Comment: To make it more clear, I was looking for a word with a more neutral connotation.

Comment: "Pulling the rug out from under someone" is not a neutral expression.

Comment: A more neutral "version" meaning roughly the same thing, if you will.

Comment: One's own feet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about [blindside](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/blindside#Verb), certain uses/connotations of [betray](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/betray#Verb) (especially senses 2 and 3), and another idiom: [throw under the bus](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/throw_under_the_bus).

Answer (score 2):

How about words like **sabotage** or **double-cross**, **countermine**, **undermine**, **derange**, or **subvert**?

Comment: Damn, you beat me to it! +1

Answer (score 1):

*[Disenfranchise](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/disenfranchise#Verb)* means  “to deprive someone of a franchise...”, a *[franchise](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/franchise#Noun)* typically being along the lines of “A right or privilege officially granted to a person, a group of people, or a company”.  This term is suitable for formal use.

Closer to the spirit of the idiom in the question (“to pull the rug out from under one's feet”) are *to [floor](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/floor#Verb) (a person)* (sense 3, “To silence by a conclusive answer or retort”) and *[to cut off at the knees](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/knee)* (13, “to squelch or humiliate (a person) suddenly and thoroughly: [eg] The speaker cut the heckler off at the knees.”

Also consider  *[undercut](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/undercut#Verb)* (“To undermine”) and synonyms, and  *[discombobulate](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/discombobulate#Verb)* (“To throw into a state of confusion; to befuddle or perplex”).

Answer (score 0):

Also: *confound, confuse, disorient*.